# Google Webtools: Fetch and Render

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

I have a question about one of the google webtools - Fetch as Google -> Fetch and Render.

I get some errors about my resources when I use it. If I use Fetch only I get "Complete" status and that is great. But if I use Fetch and Render, I get "Temporarily unreachable" status for some of my images, but if I click on a link of an image it is reachable. There could be a lot of images on my pages and I think that this feature has a limit for count of external resources that are loaded to render a screenshot image. What do you think? Has anyone encountered with this problem? Also, I wonder how many common between this feature and the real goolgebot engine? Does the googlebot get this errors too or not.. Should I worry about it or not..

Google says:

About "Partial" status - "You can assess the gravity of the situation by clicking through the missing resources. A fetch with the Partial status could mean a small problem with the page (e.g. few or insignificant resources could not be retrieved)"

- But when I click on an url that is marked as unreachable it is reachable.

For example:

http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s10/v109/p458738824-2.jpg?sn=2YH    Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s5/v124/p533056357-2.jpg?sn=2YH Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s5/v119/p79952255-2.jpg?sn=2YH  Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s5/v132/p201642078-2.jpg?sn=2YH Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s7/v152/p126202968-2.jpg?sn=2YH Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s5/v124/p189570842-2.jpg?sn=2YH Image   Temporarily unreachable 
http://cdn.zenfolio.net/img/s7/v155/p124919933-2.jpg?sn=2YH Image   Temporarily unreachable

You can try this http://www.photographercentral.com/photographers/us/louisiana/new-orleans url to test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Engine that Google use for fetch and render(FNR) is not standard browser . Many a time a valid webpage is reported by FNR as error / not reachable.Partial loading is fine but if you see error while fetching / Page loaded incorrectly then here are the measures you can take to debug the issue.

1) Create a page in your site that prints user-agent , browser version etc , and open that page using FNR . This way you will know which browser it's using and test and fix problem for that browser.
[image]

2) You can use some error aggregator tool we use track.js (others are rollbar etc), and load a particular page in FNE using some weired params . e.g. `www.example.com/pageurl?bot=93` . Now you can search `bot=93` easily in track js error list and will know what excatly are the errors generated for that page.

Answer (score 0):

you just delete www from your address then you can see complete fetech and render.
change Preferred domain, if it's with www delete www and if it's not with www add www.
its work for me.